# How do I create a diagram with multiple png images?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-raster

I am trying to create something like this, but with different images for each node. [PNG images as vertices in R (igraph)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423854/png-images-as-vertices-in-r-igraph)

I have tried using the same format but on a list of images, but I get this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("as.raster") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.raster' applied to an object of class "list"
```

```
img_train <- list.files(path = "~/Path/to/files", pattern = ".png")
img_list <- lapply(img_train, readPNG)

g <- graph.ring(5)
V(g)$raster <- replicate(vcount(g), img_list, simplify=FALSE)

plot(g, vertex.shape="raster", vertex.label=NA,
     vertex.size=1:10*5, vertex.size2=1:10*5)
```

I am not sure how raster works - so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Don't you think it should be `list.files(path="~/Path/to/files", pattern=".png", full.names=TRUE)`? (This might be an artifact of the MWE here, but I want to make sure it wasn't a contributing cause.) If this is not the case, does `str(img_list)` look appropriate?

Comment: I'm also wondering whether it should just be `V(g)$raster <- img_list`: you already have one image per node I'm assuming, so you don't need to repeat the image multiple times, and they're already in a list.

Comment: OMG. It worked! Thank you r2evans and Marius!